# SCS [Self Contained Systems] or Micro-Front End Implementations In Angular 4

Tags: angular

Any one tried SCS [Self contained systems] of Micro front ends in Angular 4 ?

**Objective :**

Develop each modules as seperate apps such that they can be coded, maintained & Deployed independently instead of building the whole app & Deploying

**Example :**

I create a common header Application. Header May be used by 100 other applications, now objective is to release new version of header independently without building all
the 100 Applications.

**Possible Options :**

1. In react I could see [tutorials](https://medium.com/@_rchaves_/building-microfrontends-part-i-creating-small-apps-710d709b48b7) and i want something very similar.

   if i follow the steps :

   a. create bundle only file [load other dependecies such as zone Js, polyfills separately so that there are no clashes] ,

   b. deploy it somewhere & load it lazily !

How does this option sound ? Will it scale for a huge application ?

2. Option i am very excited about it Universal Angular, something reported in [this issue](https://github.com/angular/universal/issues/259), but couldnt find example for the same. 
   Has any one luck in the same area ?

If anyone has any other ideas, I am all ears.

Regards !!!